# jquery sortable, draggable onto a trash can object

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having a problem with sortable, draggable item when I drop it on a trash can object.
The code is in this jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/queeg/sRAmW/1/

It's really easy to reproduce the issue in the jsfiddle:

1. drag "bread" to sortableA"
   The "sortableA" box expands to allow the item to fit.
2. drag "bread" to "Trash can"
   The trash can will expand to accept the item, then the item fades away.
3. drag "bread" from "sortableA" to the "Trash can"
   The problem will show itself.  The trash can does NOT expand and the item jumps to some other location before it fades out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution would be to remove the `position: absolute` from the draggable when dropped onto the trash can:

```
var element = ui.draggable.css('position', '');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/SCN2Q/)**

When coming from the `#sortableX` elements, they have this css rule applied, but not coming directly from one of the two lists.

Comment: Yes this appears to solve the problem very well.  I do appreciate it very much.

Comment: You're welcome. Really strange behavior, there must a reason for that but still can't figure that out.

Comment: I noticed something.  When item is dragged from "sortableA" to the trash can, an empty slot is visible.  It stays visible until the item fades away in the trash can.  Is there some way to detach the dragged item  from the sender container as soon as it is dropped?

Comment: I answered that part with this:  var element = ui.draggable.css('position', '');
  var clone = element.clone();
  clone.appendTo(this);
  element.remove();
  clone.fadeOut(1000);

Answer (score 2):

Calling `$('#sortable, #sortable2').droppable();` seems to do the trick. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sRAmW/5/).

Comment: Almost.  But when dropping from the "sortableA" the trash can doesn't expand slightly as when dropping from the lists.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are trying to append a `ul` element inside a `ul` which is not valid html and also the because of styles(left,top) it is not positioned properly after you drag and drop it inside trash which shows as if it is not dragged properly into the trash container.

I have fixed it here take a look

http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/sRAmW/3/

Comment: I appreciate any help.  In your jsfiddle the items can't be dragged from "sortableA" to the trash can anymore which is wrong functionality.